# Compilation error in the logic of exiting an App on click of hardware back button in ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, navigator, ionic5

I have created an App with following Details -
Ionic version - 5.4.16
Cordova version - 11.0.0
Angular CLI - 14.2.3
typescript - 4.8.3
npm - 8.15.0
node - 16.17.0

I want to exit an App on click of hardware back button. I have written below logic to exit the App - **navigator["app"].exitApp();**

But this logic is giving me compilation error -

**var navigator: Navigator
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"app"' can't be used to index type 'Navigator'.
Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.**

[This is the compilation error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8jAs.png)

Please help me with the solution to this error or any other way to exit an App using hardware back button in ionic 5 and cordova.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  navigator.app.exitApp();
```

in our code we do it with this line, so I think you might have the wrong syntax. I believe app is a property of navigator, you can check with a debugger. Also, are you using typeScript? That seems like a typescript error.

Comment: Yes I am using typescript with 4.8.3 version.

I tried your logic  navigator.app.exitApp(); but it gives an error as follows-
Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Then I tried writing this way - (navigator as any).app.exitapp(); which compiled successfully but gave run time error as follows - 
        
       Unhandled Promise rejection: navigator.app.exitapp is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: navigator.app.exitapp is not a function

Please let me know what actually the error is and solution to the error
Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't used typescript in cordova. The function definitely should exist. I checked where it came from and it is provided by cordova-android (You cannot programatically exit an application on iOS, you are trying this on an adndroid right?). I am not very familiar with typescript, but shouldn't you define the Navigator type to have this property app, which has this property exitApp. I think this is more a typescript issue than a cordova issue, maybe you can add that tag to get someone to help who knows more about TS.